# Undo Laravel authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have enabled Laravel authentication using this command: `php artisan make:auth`. But now I want to get rid of this. Is there any command or a way so that I can do it and remove the effect? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no command to undo it, but if you check the command at `Illuminate\Auth\Console\MakeAuthCommand`, you can see what is being changed. If you want to undo it, delete these files & folders **if you did not create them**:

**Files to be removed:**

```
app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php
resources/views/auth/login.blade.php
resources/views/auth/register.blade.php
resources/views/auth/passwords/email.blade.php
resources/views/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php
resources/views/auth/passwords
resources/views/auth
resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php
resources/views/layouts
resources/views/home.blade.php
```

And in your `routes/web.php`, delete these lines:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

---

**EDIT: Laravel 5.6**

The `MakeAuthCommand` was renamed to [`AuthMakeCommand`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/84077e6630fbfc04ec9e0908e5f8fd7dc123ce6a/src/Illuminate/Auth/Console/AuthMakeCommand.php). Generated files has not been changed. Only the generated routes has been changed slightly:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Well, this is what I did after posting this question. Surely this works, but there really should have been something to rollback the command. Thanks for answering :)